# Sql Server 2008 Exclude Company Holiday from DateDiff

Tags: sql-server-2008, datediff

I have three tables, One of which is a master calendar that houses an indicator for company Holidays. I would like to exlude Holiday from my DateDiff calculation. Below is what I have...

alert date 12/23/16
complete date 12/28/16
company Holiday 12/26/16 Need to exlude from DateDIff calculation

--My calculation shows 3 business days it should exclude 12/26/16 = 2 business days

```
 DATEDIFF(DD,A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT,S.CreatedDate) 
           -(DATEDIFF(WK,A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT,S.CreatedDate) * 2)  --HOW MANY WEEKEND DAYS PASSED BY
           -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW,A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW,S.CreatedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           -(CASE WHEN CAL.GRH_HOLIDAY_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           -(  SELECT COUNT(CAL.GRH_HOLIDAY_IND)
               FROM  A
               FULL OUTER JOIN S ON A.ID= S.ID
               INNER JOIN  CAL ON  A.ALERTCREATEDT_MMDDYYYY = CAL.CALENDAR_DATE
               WHERE 1=1
               AND Cal.GRH_HOLIDAY_IND = 'Y' 
               AND CAL.CALENDAR_DATE  between CAST(A.CREATE_DT AS DATE) AND CAST(S.CreatedDate AS DATE) ) AS BusinessDays
```

Trying to remove the Holidays is where I'm struggling, see below.

```
-(  SELECT COUNT(CAL.GRH_HOLIDAY_IND)
               FROM  A
               FULL OUTER JOIN S ON A.ID= S.ID
               INNER JOIN  CAL ON  A.ALERTCREATEDT_MMDDYYYY = CAL.CALENDAR_DATE
               WHERE 1=1
               AND Cal.GRH_HOLIDAY_IND = 'Y' 
               AND CAL.CALENDAR_DATE  between CAST(A.CREATE_DT AS DATE) AND CAST(S.CreatedDate AS DATE
```

Comment: Any other info needed?

Comment: Not sure how to handle excluding Holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 case statements you can add below statement to subtract no of days from holiday Calendar table.

```
- (select ISNULL(count(1),0) from Cal where Cal.Holiday between ALERTS_CREATE_DT AND CreatedDate )
```

Comment: The calendar is a full calendar with an indicator = y when there is a Holiday. This should be represented somehwere in the query, correct? Secondly, I'm having trouble adding this into my query above. Can youhelp?

Comment: I've updated my question, see last query piece on where I'm struggling.

Comment: @John, I though holiday calendar table will have only holiday dates. Below code you can use to subtract company holiday.  - (select ISNULL(count(1),0) from Cal where Cal.CALENDAR_DATE  between ALERTS_CREATE_DT AND CreatedDate and GRH_HOLIDAY_IND ='Y' )

Comment: Works perfectly!