# DATEDIFF - How to exlude Company Holidays

Tags: sql-server-2008, datediff

I have a company calendar table with indicators for company Holidays. I need to exclude weekends and Holidays from datediff. Below is my full query.

For example 
Alert Date 12/23/16
Create Date 12/28/16
Company Holiday 12/26/16

The below query should show 2 business days and not 3. Below this query I'll post the Holiday piece where I'm having trouble.

```
SELECT 
A.ALERT_UID,
A.ALERTCREATEDT_MMDDYYYY, 
S.CreatedDate,

DATEDIFF(DD,A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT,S.CreatedDate) 
           -(DATEDIFF(WK,A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT,S.CreatedDate) * 2)  
             -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW,A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT)   = 'Sunday'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                                                                             -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW,S.CreatedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BusinessDays

,DATEDIFF(DD,A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT,S.CreatedDate) 
           -(DATEDIFF(WK,A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT,S.CreatedDate) * 2)  --HOW MANY WEEKEND DAYS PASSED BY
           -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW,A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(DW,S.CreatedDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
           -(CASE WHEN CAL.GRH_HOLIDAY_IND = 'Y' AND CAL.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN CAST(A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT AS DATE) AND CAST(S.CreatedDate AS DATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )AS BusinessDays_ExcludingHolidays

FROM  A
FULL OUTER JOIN  S ON A.id= S.id 
INNER JOIN CAL ON  A.ALERTCREATEDT_MMDDYYYY = CAL.CALENDAR_DATE  

WHERE 1=1
AND S.CreatedDate IS NOT NULL
AND A.ALERT_UID = '2'
```

Diffculties within the query below:

```
-(CASE WHEN CAL.GRH_HOLIDAY_IND = 'Y' AND CAL.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN CAST        (A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT AS DATE) AND CAST(S.CreatedDate AS DATE) THEN 1    ELSE 0 END )AS BusinessDays_ExcludingHolidays
```

Answer (score 0):

You join to your calendar on `A.ALERTCREATEDT_MMDDYYYY = CAL.CALENDAR_DATE`, so therefore your expression

```
-(CASE WHEN CAL.GRH_HOLIDAY_IND = 'Y' 
        AND CAL.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN CAST(A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT AS DATE) 
                                AND CAST(S.CreatedDate AS DATE) 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
END
```

Will only ever return 1 when `A.ALERTCREATEDT_MMDDYYYY` is a holiday. I expect you want something like:

```
SELECT  A.ALERT_UID,
        A.ALERTCREATEDT_MMDDYYYY, 
        S.CreatedDate,
        cal.BusinessDays,
        cal.BusinessDays_ExcludingHolidays
FROM  A
FULL OUTER JOIN  S ON A.id= S.id 
CROSS APPLY
(   SELECT  TotalDays = COUNT(*),
            BusinessDays = COUNT(CASE WHEN cal.IsBusinessDay = 1 THEN 1 END),
            BusinessDays_ExcludingHolidays = COUNT(CASE WHEN cal.GRH_HOLIDAY_IND = 'Y' THEN 1 END)
    FROM    CAL 
    WHERE   cal.CALENDAR_DATE BETWEEN CAST(A.ALERTS_CREATE_DT AS DATE) AND CAST(S.CreatedDate AS DATE)
) cal
WHERE   1=1
AND     s.CreatedDate IS NOT NULL
AND     s.ALERT_UID = '2';
```

Here I have assumed that your calendar table as a column `IsBusinessDay` to mark business days (or something similar - if it doesn't it should).

Comment: The same query has been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42721702/sql-server-2008-exclude-company-holiday-from-datediff/42757086?noredirect=1#comment72686807_42757086